# What does covariance/non-covariance mean in QFT?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, special-relativity, terminology, lorentz-symmetry, covariance

I'm studying QFT using the book of Mandl and Shaw. In the first chapter they start by quantising the electromagnetic field, but in a "non-covariant" way. What do they mean by that?

They have a chapter about the covariant theory of photons (chapter 5). They say using the Coulomb gauge (as in chapter 1) results in a transverse an longitudinal split of the polarisation vectors, which is frame dependent and thus non-covariant. (?) But then later they use the same vectors again and say "this is the transverse part and that the longitudinal part" but now it suddenly is covariant. What do they mean by this?

Comment: In a word, Lorentz invariance.

Answer (score 2):

Covariance means Lorentz invariance in explicit form. For example, you may work with a specific coordinate system, and derive expressions in terms of these coordinates, but Lorentz invariance will no longer be obvious.

On the other hand, when all your formulae have is dot products ($p \cdot q$), derivatives ($\partial_\mu V^\mu$), etc - one can immediately tell that they are Lorentz-invariant. It is said that the formulae are manifestly Lorentz-invariant or just covariant in this case.

Comment: OP please note that while this is a good answer, the term *covariant derivative* means something other than $\partial_{\mu}$ in almost all modern QFT literature.

Comment: @SolenodonParadoxus good point, edited the answer